# How do I set the detail view pane title the name of the currently selected cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, master-detail

Simple enough in my head?
Select Cell - Set DETAILS panel title to name of currently selected cell.

If you need any other files, please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

My MasterViewController.h is as follows

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *objects;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
}

- (IBAction)goHome{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Root View Controller";

    //Add button to NavigationController
    UIBarButtonItem *goHome =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Home",)
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(goHome)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = goHome;


    _subjectList = @[@"Art",
                     @"Business",
                     @"Citizenship",
                     @"Computer Science",
                     @"Dance",
                     @"Design Technology",
                     @"Drama",
                     @"English",
                     @"Food Technology",
                     @"Geography",
                     @"History",
                     @"ICT",
                     @"Languages",
                     @"Life Course",
                     @"Maths",
                     @"Media Studies",
                     @"Music",
                     @"PE",
                     @"Religious Studies",
                     @"Science",
                     @"Textiles",];


}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _subjectList.count;
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
    TableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    long row = [indexPath row];
    Cell.SubjectNameLabel.text = _subjectList[row];

    return Cell;


}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        [controller setDetailItem:object];
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
        //THIS LINE BELOW IS WHERE I PLANNED ON SETTING THE TITLE?
        controller.navigationItem.title = selectedCell;
    }
}



@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `NSString` property in your `.h` file of the detail view controller. Then in `prepareForSegue` set that `string` property to the name of the `cell`. You would get the name of the cell's title from your `tableViews` data source.

This is what I mean:

In `DetailViewController.h` insert the following:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *titleName;
```

`MasterViewController.m`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    DetailViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.titleName = [self.subjectList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

In `DetailViewController.m` at `viewDidLoad` insert the following:

```
self.navigationItem.title = self.titleName;
```

Take a look at this tutorial. It should help you a lot: [detail view controller](http://www.appcoda.com/improve-detail-view-controller-storyboard-segue/)

Comment: Glad I was able to help!!